# How to clean up the middle of commits without resolving CONFLICTs but efficiently

Tags: git, commit, rebase

Hi I have a repo that I want to clean up the commit history of.

I have been using `git rebase -i HEAD~10` to pull 10 commits for example.
However, I have been always cleaning up the last block of commits.

This time, what I am trying to squash is the middle of commits.

Initially, I was trying to squash with the same method I have been using.
But as soon as I close the rebase by `:wq`, it throws a bunch of CONFLICTS files.
So I was resolving the CONFLICTS one by one.
And after issuing `:wq`, I got a bunch of CONFLICTS again.
And again and again.
It looks like it is giving me a CONFLICS after resolving CONFLICTS as many as I am squashing the middle of commits.

```bash
# sample
interactive rebase done
pick <id> commit msg
pick <id> commit msg
Next commands to do (50 remaining commands)
....
You are currently rebasing branch 'rebase' on '<id>'
(fix conflicts and then run "git rebase --continue")
...
Changes to be committed:
...
  <files that already committed...>
Unmerged paths:
...
  <files with CONFLICTS>
```

To be honest, I am not even sure why the git does not understand between the CONFLICTS even though we have committed those in the past. It seems as simple as compare the commits before and after to figure out which lines of codes are needed after the rebase.

And I have roughly 60 commits that I want squash in the middle without touching the before and after commits.

Is there a way for me to easily and quickly squash these commits without resolving the CONFLICTS between?

I would hate to spend next 2 hours just resolving the CONFLICTS and another 2 hours making sure all the files contain the same codes as before the cleanup.

Any inputs or suggestions will be much appreciated.
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You can reuse the trees from the previous conflict resolutions. Or you can enable rerere to have git try to remember previous conflict resolutions and replay them. (Though since it seems that you want the results to be identical to before the cleanup, reusing trees seems to be exactly what you want.)